# What are @ad and @addr macros in Julia?

Tags: macros, julia, julia-gen

I am going through an example for `Gen` module in Julia from [here](https://github.com/probcomp/Gen/blob/7b4467a76b3037e36f86974bbed55df33ee21865/examples/regression/basic_mala.jl) and I stumbled across this code:

```
@compiled @gen function generate_datum(x::Float64, prob_outlier::Float64, noise::Float64, 
                             @ad(slope::Float64), @ad(intercept::Float64))

    if @addr(bernoulli(prob_outlier), :is_outlier)
        (mu, std) = (0., 10.)
    else
        (mu, std) = (x * slope + intercept, noise)
    end
    return @addr(normal(mu, std), :y)
end
```

which throws

> UndefVarError: @addr not defined

And the same for `@ad` which I suspect is the same thing. As a I am new to Julia and search does not return anything vaguely relevant I am stuck. Could anybody help?

Comment: I think that those Macros are either defined in `Gen` or one of its dependancies.

Comment: I am not sure. I have installed Gen (and dependencies). Is it possible that the list of dependencies changes with the script using the library?

Comment: I just pinged the author so I'll see if I can get some eyes on it for you!

Comment: I would open an issue on the repo.

Comment: Issue opened here: https://github.com/probcomp/Gen/issues/161

Comment: Looks like you’re linking to an old commit — try changing to master and you’ll see the examples no longer use those macros :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://github.com/probcomp/Gen/issues/161, the file your link points to is no longer part of the repo. Those macros were deleted and the master branch reflects that! If you wanted to run those examples, you would need to switch to an older version of `Gen`.